# Deserialize json array using RestSharp and JSON.Net in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, restsharp

I am having an issue I have been researching and can not seem to figure out.  I am trying to deserialize Json return from a restsharp call to an api.  It worked great on my first one where there was not an array involved.  Now that I am trying to do it on a string with an array in it I am having issues.  If anybody could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

So I am trying to get Roles to be stored to my Model, but it fails because it is an array:

Here is my method:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/user/{id}", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("id", id);
var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(response.Content);
```

The error I am getting is on the above line at `var d = ...`. It says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.MyModel>' to 'Models.MyModel'
```

The response for `var response` is (trying to get Roles stored in `d` to store in model):

```
"{\"Id\":22,\"FirstName\":\"Shawn\",\"LastName\":\"John\",\"Roles\":[\"User\"]}"
```

My MyModel looks like so:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

#### Updated code

Getting this error now on the same line:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.MyModel]' because the type
requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not
a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Changed model to be :

```
public List<MyModel> Roles { get; set; }
```

and controller variable to :

```
List<MyModel> deSerialize2 = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: If `Roles` is an array, why does your model declare it as a string? The whole point of deserialization is to turn the JSON string representation of objects back into objects.

Comment: So, one of the things I notice is that your JSON response represents a single model object, not an ***array or list*** of model objects, which is what you're trying to deserialze the JSON into. I'd guess that you either need to say that you want to deserialze the JSON into a single object, or modify the JSON service to return an array of models instead of a single model.

Comment: Wait, you're not just using RestSharp, you're using the [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/) library too! Which version are you using?

Comment: Lol I had edit my model and call to act as a list, which I assume now that was not needed lol.  I thought the RestSharp was just to make the calls in restSharp and the Json was to parse the the data.  Added some new lines to my original post if helps (don't think so though).

Comment: And the roles are stored as an array in the json return correct?  I think all of the rest of the return is just simple strings.

Comment: https://github.com/adamfisher/RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your model to

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Roles is an array of strings.

Edit:  After further inspection, id is actually an integer not a string.

Also, change your deserialize call to this

```
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(response.Content);
```

The json response isn't an array.

Comment: Lol i see, I tried the List<string> and used the deserialize call as List<MyModel> deSerialize2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(response.Content); and am still getting that long error i added to original post.  And thank you for catching id lol.

Comment: No problem, if this answer worked out for you please mark it as the answer for anybody who comes across this question.

Comment: And here I thought SLU had the better programmers ;)